# Haskell syntax error!

Tags: haskell, syntax, hugs

> module Blabla (DDP, create,
>   add, remove, addTr,
>   removeTr, setAS,
>   unsetAS, accepts, show)
>   where
>  data DDP = [Integer] [Char]
>   [Char]
>   [(Integer,Char,Char,Integer,String)]
>   Integer Char [Integer]

when I write that I got that error

> Syntax error in data type declaration
>   (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad
>   layout)

what is the problem I can not figure out, thanks for helping...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DDP` has no [data constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor). Try

```
data DDP = DDP [Integer] [Char] [Char] [(Integer,Char,Char,Integer,String)]
               Integer Char [Integer]
  --  Note ^^^
```

Aside: with so many fields, it might pay off to use record syntax instead. I don't know what your type is supposed to represent, so I can't show you how to apply it to `DDP`, but the Haskell wiki's example should be clear enough:

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int, address :: String }
```

Comment: now it say,   Unknown entity "accepts" exported from module "Blabla"